# how to access output value of Special Select SQL Query in the C# program

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I programming C#,and using Linq to access Database .
I write below store procedure but I don't know , how can I access to that's return value in my program.Help me how can do it ???

```
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create Procedure [dbo].[StrPC_BDPathData_CustomSelectDistance]
    @PkPathData_Id int
As
Begin
    Select [Dstc]
    From BDPathData
    Where
        [PkPathData_Id] = @PkPathData_Id
End
```

so using this code in my program:

```
DataClassesDataContext data = new DataClassesDataContext();
int Distance =int.Parse(data.StrPC_BDPathData_CustomSelectDistance(10));
```

but there was no change in Distance value,Please help...

Comment: Post the code that uses the stored procedure.

Comment: You don't want the Stored Procedure's return value (which is either NULL or 0 in this case), but its result set.

Comment: Yes of course , How can access the [Dstc] value in my app ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you've mapped things in the ORM, but you probably want something like this:

```
DataClassesDataContext data = new DataClassesDataContext();
var Results = data.StrPC_BDPathData_CustomSelectDistance(10);
int Distance =int.Parse(Results(0).Dstc);
```